# simple XML Schema - XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following xsd file which is throwing "invalid schema" error.  I have done many complex schemas before but cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with this one, which should be very straight forward.  I know I need something after

```
<xsd:element name="ebay">
```

but what?

```
XML:
<ebay><userID></userID></ebay>


Schema:
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsd:element name="ebay">

<xsd:element name="userID">
   <xsd:simpleType>
     <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
       <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
       <xsd:maxLength value="255"/>
       <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse"/> 
     </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:simpleType>
 </xsd:element>

</xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Yeah I need this and the  <xsd:complexType> before it.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the namespace xs: to "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", you're using two namespaces but have only defined xsd. You should really just use one or the other. Also I don't believe you can use minInclusive value or maxInclusiveValue on a string.

Comment: ooops, thats through copying and pasting!  I have edited the above but still I get the error.

Comment: Have you removed the min/max inclusive value that you can't use on string?

Comment: yeah I have used this before and it doesnt throw an errror.  I have chaged it anyway and still I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="ebay">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="userID">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
              <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
              <xsd:maxLength value="255"/>
              <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse"/> 
            </xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```